# UITableViewCell textLabel, does not update until a scroll, or touch happens, while using GCD

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

Can someone help me figure this out please?

My **UITableViewCell textLabel**, does not update until I **scroll**, or **touch** it.

The **ViewController** loads, it shows the **right amount of cells**. But the content is blank. I have to touch it or scroll to make my textLabel appear.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 32.0]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSDictionary * data = [self timeForObject: [self.months objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSString *time      = [data objectForKey:@"Time"];
            NSString *totalTime = [data objectForKey:@"Total Time"];

            NSString * textLabel  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@",
                                        time, totalTime];

            [[cell textLabel] setText:textLabel];



        });
    });

    return cell;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Thank you!

Nuno

EDIT:

A call to [cell setNeedsLayout] fixes this issue. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Is this a UITableViewController or a ViewController? 

Try calling [yourTableView reloadData]; in viewDidAppear()

Comment: You are using multithreading in Loading view of `UITableViewCell`, check this link http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/08/14/cocoa-touch-circumventing-uitableviewcell-redraw-issues-with-multithreading/ for the solution, also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352638/cell-imageview-in-uitableview-doesnt-appear-until-selected

Comment: Bigger stretch then I was hoping for unfortunately. But it must be done. Thank you for both resources! Specially the blog, exetremly helpful.

Answer (score 11):

It seems that just setting the text of the cell is not enough for it to be refreshed. Have you tried putting `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` after setting the text and see what happens? BTW, since you are already using GCD to compute stuff in the background you should try to avoid doing any work at all on the main queue. I would write that piece of code more like:

```
NSDictionary *data = [self timeForObject: [self.months objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSString *time      = [data objectForKey:@"Time"];
NSString *totalTime = [data objectForKey:@"Total Time"];
NSString *textLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@", time, totalTime];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[cell textLabel] setText:textLabel];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
});
```

Comment: It's not enough unfortunately. But I did re-arrange the code to do everything in the background like you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: [cell setNeedsLayout] fixed it! =)

Comment: Thanks @nmdias - `[cell setNeedsLayout]` was what I needed.

Comment: Make sure you also perform all cell updates within the main thread block. Otherwise `setNeedsLayout` won't do anything

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be updating the cell on another thread (which is not the main thread)

Try this when you reload the tableview:

Objective-C

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Swift

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that GCD running your block in main thread with default run loop mode. Try another way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [[cell textLabel] setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 32.0]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSDictionary * data = [self timeForObject: [self.months objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSString *time      = [data objectForKey:@"Time"];
        NSString *totalTime = [data objectForKey:@"Total Time"];
        NSString *textLabel  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@", time, totalTime];

        [cell performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:textLabel waitUntilDone:NO modes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]]; //instead of using literals you could do something like this [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    });

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.listView.reloadData()
    }
```