# Image not loading immediately in Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImage` and grabbing Images associated with a news article from a news API.

The problem is, the **images for the cells on screen aren't loading** until I start scrolling on the `UITableView`.  Once I scroll past a cell, and it goes off screen, once I come back to it the Image will finally be loaded.

Here is my **`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`** code:

```
if ([feedLocal.images count] == 0) {
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"]];
}
else {    
    Images *imageLocal = [feedLocal.images objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageLocal.url];
    NSLog(@"img url: %@", imageURL);

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    __weak UITableViewCell *wcell = cell;
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageURL]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"115_64.png"]
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                              if(image == nil) {
                                  [wcell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"115_64.png"]];
                                   //];
                              }
                          }
    ];
}
```

Any idea why this would be happening?  It just seems like when the UITableView loads, the Images aren't being told to load or something until scrolling begins?

Any suggestion is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Its the refreshing issue. You have to make an NSNotification call and when each image is loaded, you have to call tableview reload data in order for it to show images instantly

Comment: Appreciate the comment @AJ112 ... Do you have a code snippet so I can see what that would look like in my code?  It makes sense, but I've never done it before, so I want to make sure I'm following you right.

Comment: In my case the downloading process is happening in the different files thats why i used NSNotificationCenter but i had the exact same problem that is images start appearing when scrolled down. Can you first just call     [self.tableView reloadData]; right after where you are downloading images and setting it to your imageview.

Comment: I call `[_tableview reloadData]` in my `viewDidLoad` initially.  But when I try to call it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for some reason I must not be able to find a spot that works, because I can't get it to refresh all of the Images.

Comment: There is no need to call reloadData in viewDidLoad. You have to call it right after [wcell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"115_64.png"]]; Let me know if it works, if it does not, let me know so i can tell you an alternate

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  The reason I call `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad` is because that is where I'm using RestKit to get the data from the API.  So I definitely need it there at least.  What are your thoughts?  And also, are you saying to put `reloadData` inside of the if `image = nil` statement, or outside of the if statement?

Comment: Tried it, and for whatever reason its still not working for me

Comment: I love to find questions describing the exact phenomena I am observing.

Comment: This is very similar to this question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352638/cell-imageview-in-uitableview-doesnt-appear-until-selected

The solution is the same; have a placeholder for your UIImageView.

Comment: @Morkrom thanks! Hope you figure it out too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have earlier encountered a similar issue and it turned out the images in the tableview were downloading correctly. The real issue you are facing is the refresh issue. When each image is downloaded, it has to be refreshed in order to be shown in the tableview. In my case, the downloading part was done in a separate file, so i used NSNotificationCenter to tell the tableview controller class to refresh it. Here is what you can do with your code:

```
if ([feedLocal.images count] == 0) {
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"]];
}
else {    
    Images *imageLocal = [feedLocal.images objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageLocal.url];
    NSLog(@"img url: %@", imageURL);

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    __weak UITableViewCell *wcell = cell;
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageURL]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"115_64.png"]
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                              if(image == nil) {
                                  [wcell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"115_64.png"]];
                                  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ImageDownloaded" object:nil];
                                   //];
                              }
                          }
    ];
}
```

and then you can call reload data using it as below:

```
- (void) imageDownloaded:(NSNotification *)notification{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This way you don't need to scroll in order to see the image, instead they will be shown right after they are downloaded.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sweet, I'll try it out tonight and see!

Comment: How I can use the completed parameter in Swift?

Answer (score 5):

There is little chance this will solve your problem, but this is too long to fit in a comment:

**Tip 1:**

If you are reusing cells, you should not do `[wcell.imageView setImage:]` in the callback. At the time the callback code is executed, there a non-null chance that `wcell` will point to a different cell in the table view than the one you wanted to change the image.

Instead, use the `indexPath` to refer to the cell you wanted to modify:

```
completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    if(image == nil) {
        UITableViewCell *actualCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [actualCell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"115_64.png"]];
    }
}
```

Note that if the cell you wanted to change the image is not shown anymore, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will return `nil`, which is absolutely fine:

> **Return Value**
>
> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

**Tip 2:**

There is no need to re-create a string when you already have one ;)

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageURL]]

[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] // imageURL is already a string
```

**Your problem**:

I'm a little bit puzzled, the code you showed really is a simple application of `SDWebImage` "how-to" examples, and I just tested with the v3.3 of the framework, and my cells update just fine. So try to reduce your code to the bare minimum to identify the real issue.

I'd say get rid of all your application logic (the `feedLocal.images` for example), and just find out if the problem actually comes from `SDWebImage` or not.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give an answer, really appreciate it!  I already changed tip #2 in my project.  Part of the problem is that the Images show up perfectly in the simulator, but not when I try it on my device.  So the original code I posted works in the Simulator, but doesn't work on the actual iPhone I'm testing on.  Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have solved your problem, but I get my problem solved by the following code.

Basic idea is to set the cell reference usable inside block and manually set the cell's image in the completed method. Hope it helps.

```
__block UITableViewCell *cell2 = cell;

id data = [[self itemArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath item]];

if ([data isKindOfClass:[MyItems class]]) {

    MyItems *myData = (MyItems *)data;
    [[cell2 imageView] setImageWithURL:[myData url]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"]
                             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                 // do check that this is the right cell to put your image
                                 // your methods here

                                 if (image) {
                                     [[cell2 imageView] setImage:image];
                                 }
    }];
}
```

For the checking if that is the right cell, I guess it is something like this (I don't have time to check it)

```
__block UITableViewCell *cell2 = cell;

id data = [[self itemArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath item]];

if ([data isKindOfClass:[MyItems class]]) {

    __block MyItems *myData = (MyItems *)data;
    [[cell2 imageView] setImageWithURL:[myData url]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"]
                             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                 // do check that this is the right cell to put your image
                                 // your methods here
                                 id currentData = [[self itemArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath item]];
                                 if ([currentData isKindOfClass:[MyItems class]] && [ [[(MyItems *)currentData url] absoluteString] isEqualToString:[[myData url] absoluteString] ]) {
                                 // it is the right cell to put in :)
                                     if (image) {
                                         [[cell2 imageView] setImage:image];
                                     }
                                 }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Excellent, is this for SDWebImage specifically or just in general this is what you use for it?  Thanks again for the response!

Comment: I write this in order to work with SDWebImage. I would never prefer writing this in general (in case you do not download image from internet). As using block reference has to be careful with the memory and leakage, I would prefer download image to a model (or some filesystem), once finish, notify the caller (UITableView in this case), update the cell image. Of course you have to work with protocol and things like that, but it has less chance that you make memory leak as using ARC by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *mainimg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[xmlDataDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"eg.main.img1"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mainimg];
NSData *imge = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.img.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imge];
```

Comment: This solution is working but there is a lag in the device when the tableview is loaded or scrolled

Comment: My table cells are dynamic...NSData will consume time to load the image which would normally happen in background if you use AFNetworking. So the delay